# inserting image path to database in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i have a form which have text fields and single image, the text field are inserting to the database successfully but image path is not inserting in database which i have stored in image variable, i am using mysql database, the image is uploading in folder but the path is not storing in database.

**The Controller File**

```
class product{
function validate_products()
{


        $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'title', 'trim|required|');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('price', 'price', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('description', 'description', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('category', 'category', 'trim|required');
        //$this->form_validation->set_rules('image', 'image', 'trim|required');

        $config = array(
        'upload_path' => "./images/",
        'allowed_types' => "gif|jpg|png|jpeg",
        'overwrite' => false,
        );  



$this->load->library('upload', $config);



        if($this->form_validation->run() && $this->upload->do_upload() )
        {

            $data =  $this->upload->data();
            $image= base_url("images/". $data['raw_name'] . $data['file_ext']);

            $post['image'] = $image;



            $this->load->model('upload_model');

            if($query= $this->upload_model->create_product())
            {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('product_sucsess', 'Product uploaded sucsessfully');
                $this->upload();

            }
            else
            {


                $this->session->set_flashdata('product_fail', 'Sorry product not uploaded .');
                $this->load->view('Admin/upload_product');

            }


        }
        else
        {

            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            $this->load->view('admin/upload_product', $error);


        }
        }
}
```

**The Model class**

```html
class upload_model extends  CI_Model
{
 public function __construct() 
     {
           parent::__construct(); 
           $this->load->database();
     }

 
 
 function create_product()
 {
  $new_member_insert_data = array(
  'title'=> $this->input->post('title'),
  'image'=> $this->input->post('image'),
  'price'=> $this->input->post('price'),
  'description'=> $this->input->post('description'),
  'category'=> $this->input->post('category'));
  
  $insert = $this->db->insert('product', $new_member_insert_data);
  return true;
 }
 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$post['image'] = $image;` does not go through `$this->input->post('image').`

You can try declaring `$post['image']` as `$_POST['image'].`

If this is not working, then you will need to manually pass in the variable to create_product function.